# CakePHP 2.6.2 - BasicAuthenticate - Call to undefined method UnauthorizedException::responseHeader()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I use a Digest Auth in my CakePHP app for protect some actions. On my PC with wamp it works, but when I push it on the server I have this error:

### **Fatal Error**

**Error:** `Call to undefined method UnauthorizedException::responseHeader()`

**File:** `.../lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php`

**Line:** `104`

/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BasicAuthenticate.php:

```
public function unauthenticated(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
    $Exception = new UnauthorizedException();
    $Exception->responseHeader(array($this->loginHeaders())); //Line 104
    throw $Exception;
}
```

Someone has an idea about the problem ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: what is in line 104 ?

Answer (score 0):

UnauthorizedException extends HttpException

HttpException has the folowing bit of code (cake 2.5.6)

```
if (!class_exists('HttpException', false)) {
    class HttpException extends CakeBaseException {
    }
}
```

If you already have HttpException defined then it will not extend CakeBaseException and probably wil not have responseHeader function implemented

check your php extensions and vendor libraries if they have HttpException

i used:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('HttpException');        
var_dump($reflector->getFileName()); //if its defined in a php file
var_dump($reflector->getExtensionName()); //if its defined in a php extension
```

to find out i have php-http extension installed that i dont need and it has HttpException class defined